# Unity Server Camera Set

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, photon

I'm currently working at a multiplayer server using unity and photon. The problem is when I spawn a character for each player I want to set the LocalCamera for that client on the character attached camera. When I have a player and I spawn the second, in the project there will be 2 active cameras at the same time (my own character camera and the other player's camera) and I don't know how to set the view on my camera. It automatically sets from what I see to the last created one. Please lend me a hand! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a script and set the camera active within. The only thing you have to check is if the client is the one who created the object.
This could be done with isLocalPlayer from the NetworkBehaviour.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour-isLocalPlayer.html

```
if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
this.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
```

Edit: My bad, this might only be support on the unityNetworking API